# jQuery - exclude inputs with certain value from selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, selector

I would like to select all inputs in my div and set them new value but also I want to exclude inputs with certain value
something like this:

```
$('#mydiv input:not(val("100")').val(myvariable);
```

how to do that, is it possible in simple selector?
thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use the [attribute not equal](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/) selector.

```
$('#mydiv input[value!="100"]').val(myvariable);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A3KrZ/)

Comment: +1 from me :-) Also here's the jquery docs with some more info: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#mydiv input:not([value="100"])').val(myvariable);
```

or

```
$('#mydiv input').filter(function() {
    return $(this).val() != 100;
}).val(myvar);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var n = jQuery("input[value!='1']").val();

alert(n);
```

check this link too

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/

Answer (score 0):

you can also use the each function.

```
$('#mydiv :input').each(function(){

    if($(this).val() != '100')
       $(this).val(myvariable);
});
```